# Как сделать сетку в консоле на C++ через for

Tags: c++, visual-c++, циклы, for

Задача, чтобы через цикл for в консоль выводилась такая сетка

[image: сетка]

До этого мы делали треугольники, квадраты, плюсы и крестики, с этим я справился сам, без проблем.
Но вот как сделать сеточку, я не особо понимаю.
Я бы не хотел просто увидеть код, а хотел бы увидеть пояснения, что нужно сделать и для чего.

Ниже код который примерно должен быть:

```
case 3:
    system("cls");
    cout << "[3] Треугольник\n\n";
    cout << "[1 | 2] Режим:  ";
    short mode;
    cin >> mode;
    cout << "[#] Размер: ";
    cin >> size;
    cout << "\n\n";
    for (;size % 2 == 0;)
    {
        nCout("Четное значение!", 12);
        cout << "[-] Размер: ";
        cin >> size;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i <= size / 2; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
        {
            if (mode == 1)
            {
                if (j == size / 2 - i || j == size / 2 + i || i == size / 2)
                    nCout("^", 3);
                else
                    nCout(".", 7);
            }
            else
            {
                if (j >= size / 2 - i && j <= size / 2 + i || i >= size / 2)
                    nCout("^", 3);
                else
                    nCout(".", 7);
            }
        }
        cout << endl;
```

Comment: Ну выводите в нужных местах -, + и | - вот и сетка в консоли...

Comment: Не совсем понятно что у вас конкретно вызвало проблему: задача ведь элементарная, судя по тому чти вы привели. Если, конечно, в эту сетку не нужно будет что-то записать - это уже задача нетривиальная

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch Просто я не понимаю, как сделать определенное кол-во отступов (1 отступ между каждой линией)

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch Если что, пользователь сам вводит size, поэтому я не могу сделать код обычным способом, постоянно прибавляя +1 или что то подобное

Comment: @KraNf а не хотите пояснить что за size, что за отступы, что значит "обычным способом"? Мы вас просто не понимаем.

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch Хорошо, простите. size - это размер фигуры который задает пользователь. Отступы это отступы от сетки, в одной линии допустим есть линия, в следующей нету: (| | | | | что то подобное, только в консоле). А под обычным способом я имел ввиду, если пользователь бы не вводил размер, то я просто мог бы в условии много раз написать j == size - 2, и все, консоль бы заполнилась как мне нужно, а из за размера я не могу это сделать, ведь пользователь может ввести 100, или 1000

Comment: Меньше слов, больше дела! Покажите **код**, как вы выводите квадраты и крестики.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Это жесть, подскажите как вставить код на этом сайте? Ставлю ` и ` в конце кода, но по итогу код выглядит ужасно

Comment: @KraNf вот это уже интереснее. Правда не понятно почему вы это написали не в вопро а в комментарий. Проблема с тем, что пользователь может ввести значения превышающие размер имеющийся области можно решить по разному, хотя обычно ограничиваются числом 80 для столбцов (у этого числа довольно интересная история). Если это вас не устраивает, то можете попробовать использовать ncurses

Comment: Вставьте код в вопрос. Удалите лишние комментарии.

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch вставил код в вопрос

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch Вы увидели код?

Comment: @KraNf зачем вы у меня это уточняете? Я его даже не просил.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
#include <iostream> 

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Ru");
    cout << "Введите размерность сетки:";
    int 1MeshSize;
    cin >> 1MeshSize;
    int k = 1;
    for (int j = 0; j < 1MeshSize; j++)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1MeshSize;i++)
        {
            cout << "_";
            cout << "|";
            if (k == MeshSize)
            {
                cout << "_";
            }
            k++;
        }
        cout << endl ;
        k = 1;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 1MeshSize; i++)
    {
        cout << " " << "|";
    }
}
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]